# How to use Email::Address to extract emails from a file with perl

Tags: perl

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
#Author Leo
use Email::Address;

#use strict;
my $file = "/var/log/maillog";
my $string="msgif";
open(MAIL, $file);
my @buffer =<MAIL>;
close(MAIL);
my $lines=grep(/$string/, @buffer);

#print "@lines";

my @addresses = Email::Address->parse($lines);
print $addresses[0]->address;
```

This is my code. I am new to perl I want to know how I can use `Email::Address` to parse lines in a file and then get the email address.

Comment: If you are new to perl, why is your code so old-fashioned?

Comment: @innaM: My guess - learning from bad sources :-)

Answer (score 3):

Untested:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;

use Email::Address;

open(my $fh, '<', '/var/log/maillog')
    or die "Cannot open /var/log/maillog: $!";

while (<$fh>) {
  next unless /msgif/;

  my @addrs = Email::Address->parse($_);

  foreach my $addr (@addrs) {
    print "$addr\n";
  }
}

close($fh);
```

Comment: Showing the three-argument-version of `open` is good, but don't forget to check for success `open my $fh , '<' , "..." or die "Cannot read ...: $!";`.

Answer (score 2):

Another idea using `File::Slurp` and `Email::Find`. You can define your search and implement it into this.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Email::Find;
use File::Slurp;

my @addresses;
my $wanted = Email::Find->new(
                  sub {
                        my ($email, $old) = @_;
                        push @addresses, $email->format;
                      });

my $data = read_file('/var/log/maillog');
$wanted->find(\$data);

print join("\n", @addresses);
```

Answer (score -2):

Or you can use Regular expression to parse the email ..